# Cleaning a text field

Tags: performance, objective-c

How can I optimize the `if` condition in this snippet? The only one difference is `&& [self isCurrentPosition:i]`. How can I make it a single `if`, including the condition `val`?

Note: `self` is a category of `NSArray`.

```
- (void) cleanTextfieldExcluding:(int)current checkPosition:(BOOL)val {
  for ( int i=0; i<[self count]; i++ ) {

    // -----------
    if ( val ) {  // this IF block is very bad
      if ( i != current && [self isCurrentPosition:i] )
        [self replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@""];
    } else {
      if ( i != current ) 
        [self replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@""];
    }
    // -----------

  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot merge it go a single if.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the code in `if` will be executed only if `i != current` and `val && [self isCurrentPosition:i]` or `!val`, so you could merge all the `if`s into one:

```
- (void) cleanTextfieldExcluding:(int)current checkPosition:(BOOL)val {
  for ( int i=0; i<[self count]; i++ ) {

    // -----------
    if ( (i != current) && (!val || [self isCurrentPosition:i]) ) {
        [self replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@""];
    }
    // -----------

  }
}
```

Comment: just saw the answer below me and OMG it was better than mines(performs one less logic operation) so i updated mines too. :P

Comment: -1. Your answers are now the same because you copied his code (and didn't upvote his answer).

Answer (score 5):

the `(val · ¬cur · pos) | (¬val · ¬cur) = ¬cur (val·pos | ¬val) = ¬cur (pos | ¬val)`. So, the condition is

```
if ( (i != current) && (!val || [self isCurrentPosition:i]) ) {
        [self replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@""];
    }
```

You just must practise factoring out the common subexpressions and subprograms and learn how to use the Carnot maps for boolean minimization.